# Is is entry to the Louvre still free for British residents or is Brexit effective as of now?

Tags: france, uk-citizens, museums, brexit, the-louvre

I am not sure if Brexit is effective which would mean we can no longer get into the Louvre museum in Paris free with an EU passport, instead and having to pay the €15/17 euros. I want to visit today and yesterday they were at capacity. We could book it online but perhaps we will just go if we can get in without paying. I am in the 18-25 age range and a UK citizen.

Comment: Do you refer to the free entry for 18-25 year old EEA residents? UK is still in the EU, but you won't get a free entry to Louvre just because you have a UK passport.

Comment: Yes this is what I'm referring to, so just to clarify if i am 18-25 and a UK citizen this will grant entry?

Comment: Brexit hasn't happend yet.

Comment: Brexit is now set for 31st October 2019. It could happen earlier than that, or later, or not at all. Nobody really knows.

Answer (score 4):

The [Louvre admissions page](https://www.louvre.fr/en/hours-admission-directions/admission#tabs) says

> 18-25 year-old residents of the European Economic Area (EU, Norway, Iceland, and Liechtenstein) enjoy free admission to the museum year round.

Britain has not left the EU, so this would still apply to you. The page does not indicate how yoou demonstrate your residency (I can have a UK passport, but am not a resident) nor how you claim the free ticket. It also doesn't suggest that this somehow gets you around being "at capacity."

Comment: According to [this page](https://www.louvre.fr/en/free-admission-musee-du-louvre), "Visitors eligible for free admission can skip the line for ticket sales and go directly to one of the entrances to the collections";  you don't need to get a ticket at all.  They might still turn you away if they're at capacity, though.